# Удаление с нескольких таблиц SQLite - Базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Имеется база данных из 4 таблиц.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется удалить по Названию теста полностью данный тест, т.е. Вопросы, Ответы, и стереть ИД с таблицы Опции ТОЛЬКО по Названию Теста.
Пример кода `SQLite`, по этому коду по Названию теста удаляет из таблицы Тесты и Опции, но в Таблице Ответы и Вопросы имеются данные относящиеся к данному тесту.

```
DELETE FROM Тесты
WHERE Тесты.id_Теста IN (
SELECT Тесты.id_Теста FROM Тесты т
INNER JOIN Опции o
ON (т.id_Теста = o.id_Теста)
WHERE Тесты.Название_Теста = 'ТЕСТ1'
);
```

Подскажите, как сделать правильное удаление записей из всех таблиц по названию теста, в таблице Опции, в настройках внешнего ключа на `DELETE/UPDATE` стоит `CASCADE`, и если удалять `ID` только из таблицы Опции, то в других таблицах все равно будут эти данные. Как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

В текущей реализации БД один вопрос или ответ может принадлежать нескольким тестам. Если Вы хоте удалять записи из этих таблиц, значит такого функционала у Вас нет. У Вас классическая ситуация "один-ко-многим". Много вопросов ссылаются на один тест, много ответов ссылаются на один вопрос.

Если я прав, то Вам нужно из таблицы вопросов добавить ссылку на тест, из таблицы ответов ссылку на вопрос, а таблицу опций удалить. Тогда, если на всех ключах будет стоять каскадное удаление, то простоя запрос

```
DELETE FROM Тесты
  WHERE Тесты.Название_Теста = 'ТЕСТ1'
```

удалит все нужные записи

Comment: Да, я тоже наверное так подумал, что опции удалить а просто сделать ссылки в другие таблицы. Сделаю отпишусь и поставлю что помогли:)